# Kotlin androidTest: Tests ran to completion. Empty test suite

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-testing, dagger-2

I'm trying to translate my tests from java to kotlin.

Simple unit tests were translated successfully, like this:

```
class BindingUtilsTest {
  @Test @Throws(Exception::class)
  fun testConvertBooleanToVisibility_visible() {
    assertEquals(BindingUtils.convertBooleanToVisibility(true), View.VISIBLE)
  }
}
```

But when I'm trying to run androidTest it fails with message: "No tests were found" and

> Test running started
>   Tests ran to completion.
>
> Empty test suite.

Code worked perfectly, when was in java. Related code:

build.gradle parts:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.neenbedankt.android-apt"

// for tests
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


// defaultConfig
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin' // tests are there
    androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin' // and there
}

// unit tests
testApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVer}"

// kotlin
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlinVer}"
testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${kotlinVer}"

// android tests

androidTestApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVer}"

// kotlin
androidTestCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlinVer}"
androidTestCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${kotlinVer}"
```

Simple test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) class MainDrawerActivityTest {

  private val mQuestions = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().applicationContext as Questions

  private val mTestComponentRule = TestComponentRule<Questions, AppComponentTest>(mQuestions,
      DaggerAppComponentTest.builder().appModuleTest(AppModuleTest(mQuestions)).build(),
      { obj, component -> obj.setAppComponent(component) }, // set test component
      { objectToClear -> objectToClear.setAppComponent(null) }) // clear test component

  private val mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(
      MainDrawerActivity::class.java, false, false)

  // TestComponentRule needs to go first to make sure the Dagger TestComponent is set
  // in the Application before any Activity is launched.
  @Rule @JvmField val mRuleChain: TestRule = RuleChain.outerRule(mTestComponentRule).around(mActivityTestRule)

  private var mActivity: MainDrawerActivity? = null

  @Before @Throws(Exception::class)
  fun setUp() {
    mActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null)

    mActivity = mActivityTestRule.activity
  }

  @Test @Throws(Exception::class)
  fun testOnCreate() {

    val size = mActivity!!.supportFragmentManager.fragments.size

    // check if fragment instantly added
    assertEquals(size.toLong(), 1)
  }
}
```

Test component is in Kotlin:

```
// Empty because extends ApplicationComponent
@Singleton @Component(modules = arrayOf(
    AppModuleTest::class)) interface AppComponentTest : AppComponent
```

And test module is also in Kotlin:

```
@Module class AppModuleTest(private val mApp: Questions) /*: AppModule*/ {
  @Provides fun provideApp(): Questions {
    return mApp
  }
}
```

I don't even see, that DaggerAppComponentTest is built.

**Why I use apt instead of kapt for tests?**

Because I've got an error that I can't mix apt and kapt in one project. I tried to switch apt to kapt and got billion of errors.

As I understand, kapt processes kotlin files and using it people generate kotlin code? And for apt: java files, java code. How to mix it? How to solve this problem?

**Solution**

Accepted solution works. Before that I returned kapt for Kotlin. With `kaptAndroidTest` and `kaptTest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@Rule @JvmField val mRuleChain: TestRule = RuleChain.outerRule(mTestComponentRule).around(mActivityTestRule)
```

to

```
@get:Rule @JvmField var mRuleChain: TestRule = RuleChain.outerRule(mTestComponentRule).around(mActivityTestRule)
```

if it won't work, it means that mRuleChain is null, check Dagger provided objects.

Comment: Yeah, this work to me. But with Realm in dependencies I have to clean project every time before tests, to make it work. Too much problems :(